# Installation of perl modules

Tags: software-installation, raspbian-stretch, perl

I´m running a Rasbian strecth 4.9.59-v7+ and I´m trying to run the following software 
https://github.com/weaknetlabs/warcarrier which looks really neat!

When trying to run the script I receive the following error code:

```
Can't locate lib/GMAPS.pm in @INC (you may need to install the lib::GMAPS module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl-base) at ./warcarrier line 29.
```

The GMAPS.pm cannot be installed via cpanm to my knowledge. However, the GMAPS.pm (with a few other modules) can be found in a subdirectory named lib to the warcarrier software. So far I have tried the following:

Copied the GMAPS.pm module to one of the above mentioned folders (`/etc/perl`)

Tried to run the script with `perl -I /home/pi/warcarrier/lib`

Modified the script by adding `use lib '/home/pi/warcarrier/lib';`(Gave me the error message that is still missing the GMAP.pm, However @inc now includes the /home/pi/warcarrier/lib directory. `Can't locate lib/GMAPS.pm in @INC (you may need to install the lib::GMAPS module) (@INC contains: /home/pi/warcarrier/lib /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl-base) at ./warcarrier line 30.`

Tried to imprt the /home/pi/warcarrier/lib to @inc with `export PERL5LIB=/home/pi/warcarrier/lib`. Error message shows that the path `/home/pi/warcarrier/lib` was NOT included in the path where @inc looked for GMAPS.pm when the script was run if that means something to anyone.

I have ran out of options, any help is much appreciated!
Kind regards!

Comment: There is nothing about the installation of perl modules that is unique to the Raspberry Pi.  This question would better asked on  our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), or our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).